# Translate "als wären seitdem Ewigkeiten vergangen"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

> Es kommt mir vor, als wären seitdem Ewigkeiten vergangen, so viel ist inzwischen passiert.

I have some trouble to understand this. I think it means:

"It feels to me as if eternities have passed since then, so much has happened in the meantime".

Is this correct? Why do we have "wären" there? I think I need to refresh my grammar about "wäre"/"hätte"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your translation is right.

Why do we have wären there? - Of course, there did not pass eternities, so it's hypothetical -> Konjunktiv II.

Comment: Ah, right, this was called `Konjunktiv II`. Thanks, I will refresh my memory of this a bit.